# Как отправлять запросы через прокси?

Tags: python, django, nginx, proxy, dokku

Бекенд моего сайта расположен на сервере с ip адресом Германии, но мне нужно отправлять запросы в другие сервисы так, как будто я нахожусь в Украине.
Я подразумеваю, что можно купить прокси этой страны и как то через него работать, но как это реализовать не знаю.
В идеале, хотелось бы глобально сменить адрес, чтобы все запросы приложения по умолчанию отправлялись именно из него, но при этом сам бекенд был доступен как и раньше по адресу, который выдал мне хостинг.

Вот технологии, которые я использую:

- python
- django
- nginx
- dokku

В питоне есть отличная библиотека requests, которая частично отвечает на мой вопрос, но мне бы не хотелось к каждому запросу прописывать прокси. Возможно можно это как то глобально применить к проекту на django?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
 
url = 'http://google.com/'
proxies = {'http': '207.164.21.34:3128'}
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('my_login', 'my_password')
 
response = requests.get(url=url, proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
response.close()
 
print(response.status_code) # 200 - good
```

Comment: через requests можно просто proxies = {'http': 'user:password@ip:port'}

Comment: Можно попробовать через `session` у `requests` задать прокси и везде использовать объект сессии

Comment: я бы поднял что-то типа анонимного сквозного [3Proxy](https://losst.ru/luchshie-proksi-servery-linux#5_3Proxy) на выделенном сервере с укрианским ip

Comment: @Jack_oS правильно ли я понял, это ставится прямо на сервере рядом с тем же nginx и по факту мой адрес меняется на тот прокси, который я подключу?
если так, то и сайт мой в таком случае теперь будет доступен по украинскому адресу.

Comment: нет, это должно быть на сервере в Украине: делаете запрос со своего бэка через этот прокси на другие сервисы, они увидят запросы с украинским ip

Comment: или просто купите прокси, поищите по "купить прокси украина" )) желательно анонимный, с гарантией "один ip в одни руки"

Comment: тогда это не совсем то, что я имел ввиду. как раз таки прокси у меня есть и как запрос через него передать я знаю, а вот можно ли как то в одном месте прописать этот прокси, чтобы все запросы через ту же библиотеку requests шли через прокси не знаю

Comment: 207.164.21.34:3128 - канадский, если что ;)

Comment: а что не так с кодом в вопросе? не делает запрос через прокси? попробуйте указать: proxies = {'http': 'http://207.164.21.34:3128', 'https': 'https://207.164.21.34:3128'}

Comment: @Jack_oS работает, но это применяется к конкретному запросу, а вот если предположим у меня 1000 различных запросов сейчас есть, то чтобы мне отправлять их через прокси - нужно все менять.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119821/discussion-between-eduard-kumskyi-and-jack-os).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задать [прокси для requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) можно словарем вида
`{'http': 'http://user:pass@address:port'}`:

```py
import requests

login = 'my_login'
password = 'my_password'
address = '207.164.21.34'
port = '3128'

proxies = {
    'http': f'http://{login}:{password}@{address}:{port}',
    'https': f'https://{login}:{password}@{address}:{port}',
}
```

а проверить работоспособность каким-нибудь сервисом

```py
url = 'https://ifconfig.me/all.json'
```

который в ответ на ваш

```py
r = requests.get(url=url, proxies=proxies)
>>> json.loads(r.content)
```

вернет, среди прочего, ip, с которого пришел запрос:

```py
{
    'ip_addr': '207.164.21.34', 
    'remote_host': 'unavailable', 
    'user_agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 
    'port': 55952, 
    'method': 'GET', 
    'encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'mime': 
    '*/*', 
    'via': '1.1 google', 
    'forwarded': '207.164.21.34, 216.239.32.21'
}
```